# Passing file descriptors from one Activity to other

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parcelable, file-descriptor

I am trying to pass a FileDescriptor from one activity to another. The only way i found out was to use Parcel and pass a ParcelFileDescriptor. But the ParcelFileDescriptor is duplicate of the original Filedescriptor with different fd. I want the same fd to be passed to the other activity.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Perhaps what you want to do could be done with a ContentProvider. There is also the posibility to store the File Descriptor in the Application class (You need to extend Application and set it the manifest)